# Why do I have loop partitions mounted?

Tags: partitioning

[image: This image shows a partition problem]

What is this problem in Ubuntu 16.04? I have had this problem for 2 months now and I can't seem to be able to delete partitions `loop0`,  `loop1`, or `loop3`.

Comment: Loop partitions are usually disk images. Unmount any game ISOs you have.

Comment: @DavidFoerster done.

Comment: @DavidFoerster although dobey's answer is much more relevant. I can't delete in mobile, but his is more worthy of the accept.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Ah, I didn't see that one from review. Never mind then. Up-votes for both of you!

Answer (score 6):

This is not a problem and those aren't partitions on your disk. They are loopback mounts.

You have installed some *snap* packages. The way snaps work is that the package is actually a *squashfs* file system. In order to use the snaps, they must be mounted. These mounts appear as loopback mounts of the *squashfs* type. This is completely normal and not a problem at all.

Comment: Can we hide them somehow? They are causing confusion while browsing files.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/loopX` partitions are usually disk/disc images (ISO, IMG, etc) that have been mounted, either by commands or by "opening" the image in a file browser

Judging from the mount points, it looks like you've mounted some game ISOs. Just open your file browser and hit the eject button next to the mounted images. That'll get rid of the partitions.

By the way, there's no harm in keeping those mounted. Ubuntu is merely treating the source images as physical drives, so no extra space is taken.

Comment: They are clearly not ISOs. They are snaps.

Comment: @dobey I know, but I can't delete on mobile for some reason.