# How to handle unused loop partition after removing snap/snapd?

Tags: command-line, kernel, snap, loop-device

While working on an Ubuntu Server for personal use, I removed what would not be necessary for my usage. It is snapd & snap that I would like to properly clean.

I removed snap and snapd using the neatest way possible (`snap remove <the default installed snap:core,lxd,snapd>` + `apt remove --purge snap`). It indeed remove the daemond, the cache,the `/snap` folder however but it doesn't clean the loop parititon, it's unmounted for the moment.

There is a mention of an additional cleanning command I should have run before uninstall all but it's too late. Command would have been `snap remove --purge <installed snap:core,lxd,snapd>`, mention [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195388/how-to-remove-dev-loops).

**How can I remove those loop partition in the best way possible ?

Would it be hard to re install snap latter ? (if needed)**

See result of lsblk :

```shell
>$lsblk -a
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0     0B  1 loop
loop1                       7:1    0     0B  1 loop
loop2                       7:2    0     0B  1 loop
loop3                       7:3    0     0B  1 loop
loop4                       7:4    0     0B  1 loop
loop5                       7:5    0     0B  1 loop
loop6                       7:6    0     0B  0 loop
loop7                       7:7    0     0B  0 loop
sda                         8:0    0 279.4G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part
[...]
```

the used distrib bellow

```shell
>$uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-83-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 14 09:30:42 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

#### Update I

There is no doubt loop{0..7} was associated with snap, see bellow the output of command *before* removing snap :

```shell
>$ lsblk -a
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/2015
loop1                       7:1    0 111.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24322
loop2                       7:2    0    87M  1 loop /snap/lxd/27037
loop3                       7:3    0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop4                       7:4    0  40.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20671
loop5                       7:5    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2182
loop6                       7:6    0     0B  0 loop
loop7                       7:7    0     0B  0 loop
sda                         8:0    0 279.4G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part
[...]
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting ?

Comment: I haven't had snap installed for a long time, yet I still have loop{0..7}, so it must be normal and unrelated to snap

Comment: @S.PUYGRENIER Ubuntu allocates 8 loop devices. Snap uses 6 of them. Your bar has 8 chairs and 6 customers come. When you kick out the 6 drunks, you don't need to throw out your 8 chairs

Comment: @DanielT, you might have a similar remaining snap parition then. See section `Updated I`, of the question, the previous mount point of loop{0..7} (before deleting) are explicitly linked to snap

Comment: @SorenA, just try to reboot but they have not been deleted : Daniel T is certainly right (thanks anyway for the idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of `loop{0..7}` is not related to snap. Snap merely used 6 of them. Just because snap used 1GB of your hard disk, doesn't mean that you need to throw away your 1TB hard disk to get rid of snap.

If you run `ls /dev` in https://bellard.org/jslinux/vm.html?url=alpine-x86.cfg&mem=192 , you will see the `loop{0..7}`. That is Alpine Linux, and is not based off of Ubuntu, so it never supported snap. Yet without snap, it still has those loop devices. This is normal.

Comment: Thanks, your answer and comment are really great.  I had complementary explaination [there:/dev/loopX partitions are usually disk/disc images (ISO, IMG, etc) that have been mounted,...](https://askubuntu.com/a/845204/1771230)

Answer (score 3):

Those `loop` devices are not necessarily specifically created for SNAP or any other app for that matter, although free ones can be utilized for any app that needs a `loop` device at any time.

Those 0-7 are automatically created at init time by the kernel (*regardless of the presence of the SNAP package manager or the `snapd` daemon*)... Quoting from [The kernel’s command-line parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html#the-kernel-s-command-line-parameters):

> ```
> max_loop=       [LOOP] The number of loop block devices that get
> (loop.max_loop) unconditionally pre-created at init time. The default
>                 number is configured by BLK_DEV_LOOP_MIN_COUNT. Instead
>                 of statically allocating a predefined number, loop
>                 devices can be requested on-demand with the
>                 /dev/loop-control interface.
> ```

... `max_loop=` used to be set to `8` for historical functionality limitation of `losetup(8)` not being able to dynamically create new loop block devices at run-time before the utilization of the `/dev/loop-control` interface to do that became possible around the year 2011 ... Which then became both unneeded and none-preferably hard limiting ... Quoting from [[PATCH 3/3] loop: add BLK_DEV_LOOP_MIN_COUNT=%i to allow distros 0 pre-allocated loop devices](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/1312053220.1187.14.camel@mop/):

> ```
> + /*
> +  * If max_loop is specified, create that many devices upfront.
> +  * This also becomes a hard limit. If max_loop is not specified,
> +  * create CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP_MIN_COUNT loop devices at module
> +  * init time. Loop devices can be requested on-demand with the
> +  * /dev/loop-control interface, or be instantiated by accessing
> +  * a 'dead' device node.
> +  */
> ```

... so it now appears to be set to `0`/unspecified ... Moreover, quoting from [[PATCH v1] loop: Fix the max_loop commandline argument treatment when it is set to 0](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20221208200605.756287-1-isaacmanjarres@google.com/T/):

> ```
> The max_loop commandline argument can be used to override the
> value of CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP_MIN_COUNT. However, when max_loop is set
> to 0 through the commandline, the current logic treats it as if it had
> not been set, and creates CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP_MIN_COUNT devices
> anyway.
> ```

... and `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP_MIN_COUNT` in Ubuntu is:

```
$ grep 'CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP_MIN_COUNT' /boot/config-"$(uname -r)"
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP_MIN_COUNT=8
```

... also reflected in:

```
$ cat /sys/module/loop/parameters/max_loop 
8
```

**Therefore** you can limit the number of loop devices created during boot time under current kernels to **one** by setting the kernel's boot parameter "`max_loop=1`" in your boot manager i.e. GRUB and supposedly to **none** under future patched kernels with "`max_loop=0`" ... and that shouldn't affect future reinstall of the SNAP package management system as loop devices should be dynamically created as needed.